# Scorm Suspend Data issue migrating from scorm cloud

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2

I currently have a client that has a Scorm 1.2 course which is hosted on Scorm cloud.  Things are going fine there with the course but the client wants to get off Scorm cloud because the fees are adding up.  I know Scorm cloud is a very in depth application but all the client really needs to worry about is allowing the user to continue where they left off, detecting if the user passed the final score and ideally the score they got on the final exam.

I have used a few different scorm player wrappers but I am running into the same issue with them all.  The scorm course made from storyboard creates a huge value for suspend_data and when it is really long for some reason the course will ask if the user wants to continue where they left off but will bring them back to the beginning and not continue where they left off.

I know to be Scorm 1.2 compliant the suspend_data should be no longer than 4096 characters but some are upwards of 90,000 characters.  I also have read Scorm doesn't really enforce this it is mainly a LMS restriction on field size.  I am storing all of the cmi data into a medium_text field so I am not having an issue with storing it.

My main question is has any migrated off scorm cloud and took their users history (suspend_data) with them to have users continue where they left off with your scorm player?  Another question is has anyone had this issue and is there a player/wrapper you have used to successfully use a large suspend_data for a Scorm 1.2 course.  What I am trying to do is take them off Scorm cloud so I can do an api call to get all of the cmi data for each user and then start launching directly from their site and store new cmi data but we can't move away since many users would have to start the course over.

I did run more tests with my scorm player and when through the entire course and saved my suspend_data at various points and I can get it to launch at that point.  The longest my suspend_data was just under 30k characters.

Any tips in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You may really want to consider using this change as a chance to upgrade to using xAPI. This does everything SCORM can do, but it can do it both online AND offline since it actually just sends specially formatted API statements. 

Here is a link to its Spec: https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec

Comment: I will look further into this but just wondering if I would be able to use the existing users suspend data from Scorm cloud to continue where they left off.

Comment: I don't think SCORMCloud monkeys with the suspend data in any way.   How could it?   Everything would break.   Just my opinion; it's a bit crazed, but it might even work.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating SCORM data from system to system is tough as while the SCORM elements themselves should be named similarly in the systems SCORM implementation, each LMS could store/name them in a different manner.

As far as the large suspend data issue goes, are you moving to a system that allows for a customized maximum suspend data size?  In SCORM Cloud and LMSs that run our SCORM Engine, we do have that course property that allows you to store as much suspend data as you want.  There are a number of LMSs out there that use Engine so you may be able to modify that behavior.

Shoot us a message at support@scorm.com if you have any other questions!

Thanks,

Joe Donnelly
Rustici Software Support